# Add multiple Vega/vincent charts to a Folium popup

Tags: python, folium, vega

I would like to add two charts to a Folium map popup using Vincent/Vega. I created two vincent objects with the charts and tried to add both of them to a Popup instance by chaining two `add_child()` methods. But only the second chart gets rendered.

Here's the code I used, but without the data, just a description of the data used for the charts.

```
from folium import Map, CircleMarker, Vega, Popup
from vincent import Bar
import math

map = Map(zoom_start=8, tiles='cartodbpositron',
             location = [-73.5, 45.2]))

# zones is a pandas dataframe with lat/lng pairs of points.

for i, zone in zones.iterrows():
    # weekday_pings: a pandas groupby aggregation of most frequent day of week in a dataframe
    # hour_pings: a pandas groupby aggregation of most frequent hour of day in a dataframe

    dayvega = Bar(weekday_pings, width=300,
               height=150).axis_titles(x='Weekday', y='Pings')
    daychart = Vega(dayvega.to_json(), width=vega.width+50, height=vega.height+50)


    timevega = Bar(hour_pings, width=300,
               height=150).axis_titles(x='Hour', y='Pings')
    timechart = Vega(timevega.to_json(), width=vega.width+50, height=vega.height+50)


    map.add_child( CircleMarker(
        location = [zone['latitudeE7'], zone['longitudeE7']],
        radius = int(math.sqrt(zone['cluster_size'])/10 + 2),
        fill_opacity = 0.8, color=None,
        fill_color = ('#274cc9'),
        popup = Popup(max_width=chart.width[0]).add_child(daychart).add_child(timechart)
    ) )
```

Here's the result: only the second child is rendered.

[image: folium popup in Jupyter]

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I didn't find a solution so I switched to Altair for the charts, using the [compound chart constructor](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html) to make multiple charts in one figure.

---

Answer (score -1):

Found this source, it might prove useful:
https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1422

To clarify:

An .html file or html code can be created containing two or more charts (Vanderplas, 2019):

```
import altair as alt
import folium
import pandas as pd

two_charts_template = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@{vega_version}"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@{vegalite_version}"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@{vegaembed_version}"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="vis1"></div>
<div id="vis2"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  vegaEmbed('#vis1', {spec1}).catch(console.error);
  vegaEmbed('#vis2', {spec2}).catch(console.error);
</script>
</body>
</html>
"""


df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(5), 'y': range(5)})

chart1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(x='x', y='y')
chart2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(x='x', y='y')

with open('charts.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(two_charts_template.format(
        vega_version=alt.VEGA_VERSION,
        vegalite_version=alt.VEGALITE_VERSION,
        vegaembed_version=alt.VEGAEMBED_VERSION,
        spec1=chart1.to_json(indent=None),
        spec2=chart2.to_json(indent=None),
    ))
```

The file is now available, it can be read back in, so:

```
html_file = open('charts.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
charts_code = html_file.read()
```

And this can be put in the map:

```
# In case a file is not needed a direct assignment can be used
# charts_code = two_charts_template.format(
#            vega_version=alt.VEGA_VERSION,
#            vegalite_version=alt.VEGALITE_VERSION,
#            vegaembed_version=alt.VEGAEMBED_VERSION,
#            spec1=chart1.to_json(indent=None),
#            spec2=chart2.to_json(indent=None),
#        )

iframe = branca.element.IFrame(html=charts_code, width=1500, height=400)
popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2000)

folium.Marker([51.5,-0.11], popup=popup).add_to(a_map)
a_map
```

Hope it helps.

References:

Vanderplas, J. (2019) 'Multiple Charts in one HTML #1422' [Online]. Available at https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1422 (Accessed 26 February 2022).